# Handling spring-exception using basePackages attribute in @RestControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `@RestControllerAdvice` annotated class with using `basePackages`attribute:

```
@RestControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.my.pkg")
public class AppExceptionV2Handler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
  @Override // isn't called
  protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported( 
          HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException ex,
          HttpHeaders headers,
          HttpStatusCode status,
          WebRequest request)
  {
    log.warn(ex, ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, headers, HttpStatus.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE);
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(SpecificPkgException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handle handleSpecificPkgException(
          SpecificPkgException ex)
  {
    log.warn(ex, ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
 }
```

The problem is that `handleHttpMediaTypeNotSupported` isn't called (by calling endpoint with wrong content-type header), if I define `basePackages = "com.my.pkg"`. Without `basePackages` it works.

I tried to add springframework package:
`@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"com.my.pkg", "org.springframework"})`,
but it doesn't work.

How can I fix it?